# Conditional Calculation in R Dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

IF i have the following dataframe:

```
tibble(date = c("2019end", "2020q1", "2020q2", "2020q3", "2020q4", "2021q1", "2021q2", "2021q3", "2021end"), 
           company = c("google","google","google","google","google","google","google","google","google" ), 
           value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
```

And a condition i have on the data is to calculate the differences between periods and years e.g. 2021q1 - 2020q1 = change between those values.

For the specific case when a q4 value is given for one year, but "end" is not given for the following year (ahead or behind)

for example in the above dataframe, 2020q4 is given, but 2021q4 is not given, but 2021end is given. hence calculation would be 2021end - 2020q4

And also vice versa, so if 2020end was given, but 2021Q4 was given, then the calcuation would be 2021Q4 - 2020end

So for the example above dataframe,
in this case, i would like to do the calculation of change as 2021end - 2020q4.

How can i code this scenario out?

Effectively this is what the table should look like:

```
| date | company| value| change|
| - | - |-|-| 
|2019end| google|1|1-NA|
| 2020q1  | google|2|2- NA |
| 2020q2| google|3|3-NA |
| 2020q3  | google|4|4-NA |
| 2020q4  | google|5|5-NA |
| 2021q1  | google|6|6-2 = 4 |
| 2021q2  | google|7|7-3 = 4 |
| 2021q3  | google|8|8-4= 4 |
| 2021end  | google|9|9-5 =4|
```

Response to r2Evans Answer:

If i would like to calculate the change in percentage terms with reference to the original periods value.

So for example at this stage:

```
dat %>%
  separate(date, c("year", "qtr"), sep = 4) %>%
  mutate(qtr = factor(qtr, levels = c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "end"))) %>%
  complete(year, qtr, company) %>%
  arrange(year, qtr) %>%
  fill(value) %>%
  pivot_wider(c(company, year), names_from = "qtr", values_from = "value") %>%
  group_by(company) %>%
  mutate(across(-year, ~ c(NA, diff(.))))
```

When we get to the across statement, how can i do the following calculation, for example taking 2021q1:

(2021q1 - 2020q1)/2020q1

as this would be the relevant change
and then again for all the other periods so it would be:

(2021q2 - 2020q2)/2020q2

(2021q3 - 2020q3)/2020q3

(20201q4 - 2020q4)/2020q4

(2021end - 2020end)/2020end

This includes where end is in place of q4.

I think this is a custom function in across

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up front, try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # complete, separate, unite, fill, pivot_*
dat %>%
  separate(date, c("year", "qtr"), sep = 4) %>%
  mutate(qtr = factor(qtr, levels = c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "end"))) %>%
  complete(year, qtr, company) %>%
  arrange(year, qtr) %>%
  fill(value) %>%
  pivot_wider(c(company, year), names_from = "qtr", values_from = "value") %>%
  group_by(company) %>%
  mutate(across(-year, ~ c(NA, diff(.)))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(company, year), names_to = "qtr", values_to = "change") %>%
  unite("date", c("year", "qtr"), sep = "") %>%
  left_join(dat, ., by = c("company", "date"))
# # A tibble: 9 x 4
#   date    company value change
#   <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 2019end google      1     NA
# 2 2020q1  google      2     NA
# 3 2020q2  google      3     NA
# 4 2020q3  google      4     NA
# 5 2020q4  google      5     NA
# 6 2021q1  google      6      4
# 7 2021q2  google      7      4
# 8 2021q3  google      8      4
# 9 2021end google      9      4
```

---

Interim steps:

First, separate `year` from `qtr`, convert into factors (for ordering) and ensure we see all five (q1-5 and end) for each year. This produces some `NA` before our observed data, no problems. We fill `NA` values with the preceding (by quarter) value, so that we can handle your corner-case of `end-q4`.

```r
dat %>%
  separate(date, c("year", "qtr"), sep = 4) %>%
  mutate(qtr = factor(qtr, levels = c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "end"))) %>%
  complete(year, qtr, company) %>%
  arrange(year, qtr) %>%
  fill(value)
# # A tibble: 15 x 4
#    year  qtr   company value
#    <chr> <fct> <chr>   <dbl>
#  1 2019  q1    google     NA
#  2 2019  q2    google     NA
#  3 2019  q3    google     NA
#  4 2019  q4    google     NA
#  5 2019  end   google      1
#  6 2020  q1    google      2
#  7 2020  q2    google      3
#  8 2020  q3    google      4
#  9 2020  q4    google      5
# 10 2020  end   google      5
# 11 2021  q1    google      6
# 12 2021  q2    google      7
# 13 2021  q3    google      8
# 14 2021  q4    google      8
# 15 2021  end   google      9
```

Pivot wider, handy now as we can do row-wise (across quarters) across years.

```r
... %>%
  pivot_wider(c(company, year), names_from = "qtr", values_from = "value")
# # A tibble: 3 x 7
#   company year     q1    q2    q3    q4   end
#   <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 google  2019     NA    NA    NA    NA     1
# 2 google  2020      2     3     4     5     5
# 3 google  2021      6     7     8     8     9
```

Calculate the differences.

```r
... %>%
  group_by(company) %>%
  mutate(across(-year, ~ c(NA, diff(.)))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 3 x 7
#   company year     q1    q2    q3    q4   end
#   <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 google  2019     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 2 google  2020     NA    NA    NA    NA     4
# 3 google  2021      4     4     4     3     4
```

Pivot back into long format. Unite the `year`/`qtr` columns back into the original `date` strings. Note that we have more rows than the original data, which will be resolved in the next step.

```r
... %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-c(company, year), names_to = "qtr", values_to = "change") %>%
  tidyr::unite("date", c("year", "qtr"), sep = "")
# # A tibble: 15 x 3
#    company date    change
#    <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>
#  1 google  2019q1      NA
#  2 google  2019q2      NA
#  3 google  2019q3      NA
#  4 google  2019q4      NA
#  5 google  2019end     NA
#  6 google  2020q1      NA
#  7 google  2020q2      NA
#  8 google  2020q3      NA
#  9 google  2020q4      NA
# 10 google  2020end      4
# 11 google  2021q1       4
# 12 google  2021q2       4
# 13 google  2021q3       4
# 14 google  2021q4       3
# 15 google  2021end      4
```

And then we left-join this new data onto the original data, which removes the extra `date` rows we created.

---

### Update

Per comments and the changed question, try this:

```r
dat %>%
  separate(date, c("year", "qtr"), sep = 4) %>%
  mutate(qtr = factor(qtr, levels = c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "end"))) %>%
  complete(year, qtr, company) %>%
  arrange(year, qtr) %>%
  fill(value) %>%
  pivot_wider(c(company, year), names_from = "qtr", values_from = "value") %>%
  group_by(company) %>%
  mutate(
    across(matches("^(q[0-9]+|end)$"),
           ~ c(NA, sprintf("(%s-%s)/%s", .[-n()], .[-1], .[-1])), .names = "{.col}_eqn"), 
    across(matches("^(q[0-9]+|end)$"),
           ~ c(NA, diff(.) / .[-1]), .names = "{.col}_val")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-matches("^(q[0-9]+|end)$")) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(company, year), names_pattern = "(q[0-9]+|end)_(.*)", 
               names_to = c("qtr", ".value")) %>%
  unite("date", c("year", "qtr"), sep = "") %>%
  left_join(dat, ., by = c("company", "date"))
# # A tibble: 9 x 5
#   date    company value eqn           val
#   <chr>   <chr>   <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
# 1 2019end google      1 NA         NA    
# 2 2020q1  google      2 "(NA-2)/2" NA    
# 3 2020q2  google      3 "(NA-3)/3" NA    
# 4 2020q3  google      4 "(NA-4)/4" NA    
# 5 2020q4  google      5 "(NA-5)/5" NA    
# 6 2021q1  google      6 "(2-6)/6"   0.667
# 7 2021q2  google      7 "(3-7)/7"   0.571
# 8 2021q3  google      8 "(4-8)/8"   0.5  
# 9 2021end google      9 "(5-9)/9"   0.444
```

Comment: If my change formula instead of minus, became this: (period_ahead value - period_behind value)/period_behind value - how would i add this in? I know this will be in the mutate(across)) section, but it is not a simple difference? Thanks for explaining above

Comment: effectively the above means that the calculation in the across() function is the difference between both periods/the period priors value

Comment: The current `change` variable is across years, so effectively `2021q1 - 2021end`. I think you're now asking for `2021q2 - 2021q1`, is that right?

Comment: I have updated the question to have an additional calculation - as there is not enough space here, please see the update

Comment: Change from `~ c(NA, diff(.)))` to `~ c(NA, diff(.)/.[-n()])`, that will get your different calculation. As you surmised, it is just changing the function within `across`.

Comment: is there a way to keep the values used in the calculation from across? e.g. can i make a paste0() statement to keep string values of those values e.g. ((30-20)/10) which is the underlying values formula of the above in string format?

Comment: See my edit please

Comment: Thanks! Clever use of across with regex patterns!